# How do I use Imagemagick to replace a gray gradient background

Tags: background, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have several photos for which I need to remove the background (replace it with #ffffff)

I have tried several ways, but none that gives a good result.

eg. `convert "$i" -fuzz 10% -fill '#ffffff' -opaque white $i-new.png`

This makes the result whiter and creates a rather harsh line between the white color and the shadow.

[image: image that needs background removed]

More sample images

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a flood fill using the colour from the top-left corner:

```
convert cauli.jpg -fuzz 10% -fill red -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png
```

[image]

Probably use a white fill though :-)

Comment: I just tried some thing that gave me a simular result.. convert "$i" -fill white -fuzz 6% -draw 'alpha 255,255 floodfill' -draw 'alpha 0,0 floodfill' "processed/$i"  .... I guess both will do the job?!.. no I just need to make it fade out to white.. any ideas? (I dont want to have the sharp edge on the shadow...

Comment: Just tried it out on some more images and got.. well.. let's call it various results :P

Comment: Automatically removing backgrounds with shadows is very hard to do if the colors in the image object are close to the background/shadow color. You can try some interactive tools like clipping magick (https://clippingmagic.com) or try OpenCV graph-cut.

Comment: It is definitely a non-trivial problem - those video folk came up with Chroma Keying (green-screening) especially for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key